# Changing source dataset for maps in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

Is it possible to change the source dataset for an existing map? I want to use a previously developed map with an updated dataset (same basic structure).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180964/can-i-change-an-existing-cartodb-map-to-use-a-different-dataset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Editor you would add a new layer using the updated dataset, & could copy the CSS/SQL over from the old layer. If you're using CartoDB.js with layers created from SQL queries of your dataset, it's even easier: just change the dataset name in the code. CartoDB also has a sync tables feature, so your data would automatically be updated from the sync source at a certain interval. That has to be set up when your dataset is first imported though: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/realtime_maps_sync/