# Update carto map with new dataset without re-styling

Tags: carto

I have been using a dataset "dataset 1" for a Carto map for some time, so it is now outdated. I have an updated dataset that contains more row data but same structure.

How do I update my map with the new dataset without having to re-style the map again? I am using Carto builder.

Here [Can I change an existing Cartodb map to use a different dataset?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180964/can-i-change-an-existing-cartodb-map-to-use-a-different-dataset), the user offers a solution, which is create a new layer using the updated dataset, then copy and paste the previous CSS into the new layer.

However, I would still need to re-style the pop-up info window. Furthermore, will I also have to re-create my widgets?

Answer (score 2):

If the updated dataset have the same columns, you can go to the SQL menu and change the current SQL query of the map:

SELECT * FROM outdatedDataset

to

SELECT * FROM updatedDataset

And click: "Apply".
By doing this change in the FROM statement of the SQL, the new layer will be loaded on the map keeping the styles of the layer and of the popups. You would need to keep the query applied on the map.